# How do I display vertical images from my 5D Mark IV sideways?

Tags: canon-5d-mark-iv

Sometimes my clients want to see vertical shots that I’ve taken of them. However, the camera displays the vertical image horizontally, making it really hard to see what’s going on.

I’d prefer it if the camera could show the image vertically. I would like it even more if it could just auto rotate—if I’m holding the camera vertically, it should make the vertical photo fill up the screen according to the orientation.

However, I could not find a setting to do this. Is there any way apart from manually rotating the photo, displaying it, and then rotating it back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Page 444 of the 5D Mk IV manual shows you three Auto Rotate options for image playback.

In the yellow tools menu, select Auto Rotate to the middle "Only on computer" option.

[image]

Comment: This is pretty strange. When I have the first option on, it forcibly doesn’t rotate vertical images. When I have the second one on, it forcibly rotates vertical images. Isn’t there a way on which it respects the orientation my camera is actually in? So for example if I rotated it vertically the other way, it would notice that and rotate it right instead of left?

Comment: I saw this setting, but thought that the first option would definitely rotate it when I played back. The description even says so. That’s why I never tried option 2. Definitely rather unintuitive…

Comment: @SkeletonBow It's always seemed perfectly intuitive to me. When it is turned off, the image is shown on the back of the camera in the same orientation it was collected by the sensor. No matter which way the camera is turned, what was on one side of a part of the camera when it was being captured is shown on the same side of that part of the camera. When it is turned on during capture, the image is turned to be shown on the LCD (which is assumed to always be held horizontally when using the review feature) based on which way the camera was oriented when it was taken, not when it is viewed.

Comment: @SkeletonBow Another way to look at it: the setting is about how a tag placed in the image is set, not how the screen is set to display anything. If the image was captured with auto rotate turned on, the image tag tells the camera to rotate the image to counteract however the camera was held differently than conventional horizontal orientation when the shot was captured. If the image was captured with auto rotate turned off, the image will not be rotated when the image is viewed, no matter what the setting is at the time the image is viewed.

Comment: @MichaelC I suppose I was expecting it more to work like a phone, which can detect the orientation the device is in and then adjust portrait/landscape photos so that it always displays upright

Comment: It's not like a phone. It seems to be based on the assumption the review will be on a desktop or laptop computer. If you really want to make it easy for your subjects to see shots you've just taken, you can shoot tethered to a laptop, or even a desktop.